# Want to display red-border on required form textfields if they are empty with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

So as the title says I want to give my form textfield a red border if they are required and happen to be empty on submit. I searched the internet to see if i could find how to do that but with no success... I already added .required to my form control and it does display "This field is required" below the texfields but without the red border. Can someone tell me what i did wrong?
My code looks like this at the moment:

```
<form id="addEditDivisionForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">
                    @GlobalResources.Division <span class="mandatory">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control required" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
                <input type="button" id="btnSaveDivision" value=" @GlobalResources.Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want it to look something like this:
http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: The link you provided literally tells you how to do it...

Comment: Invalid inputs should have `input-validation-error` or similar class, you can apply some CSS rules to it.

Comment: As mentioned by @Deckerz link provided by you clearly shows how to accomplish this. why dont you try `validator.js`.

Comment: I tried what is in the page i provided and i don't get the wanted output. When i apply "required" like this @class = "form-control required"  the border of my texfield does not become read. I just get an error message like "This field is required" under it.

Comment: `required` is a HTML-5 attribute and has nothing to do with MVC's client side validation (and if you have implemented client side validation, then your `required` attribute is ignored anyway - the `jquery.validate.js` plugin add `novalidate="novalidate" to your `<form>`)

Comment: I found out what i had to do. I just had to add : .form-control.error {
    border-color: #E74C3C;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
} to my css

Answer (score -1):

I finally found what i was looking for. It was very simple i just had this code below to my CSS and the problem was fixed:

```css
.form-control.error {
    border-color: #E74C3C;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```